# Pixel art in native iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pixel

I am looking for some library for creating pixel art in objective c, in which I can copy/cut paste or flip selected area.

Almost cover major actions of windows Paint app. Is there any library or something by which I can achieve this.

Something similar to [Make Pixel Art App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/make-pixel-art/id482186692)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two use full links:

Swift:

https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2015/06/15/lets-build-freehand-drawing-in-ios-part-1/

Objective C:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164